# How do I mix UIKit and SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, sprite-kit

I am making a game in Swift. I have used both UIKit and SpriteKit, but never in the same app. I was wondering how to leverage the power of both of them (They are going to be a lot of menus). If you knew a tutorial I could use, or could tell me, I would be very appreciative. I also would like to know if there is a shortcut for this in xcode (e.g. storyboards)

Comment: "how to leverage the power of both" ... do you want the answer to this in a single sentence and gift-wrapped? The question is far too broad, we have no idea what you're even trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi I wrote a tutorial on how to do this with downloadable project. If anybody is interested you can go to: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2016/11/how-to-embed-spritekit-in.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to stick with SpriteKit and to create menus etc with `SKNodes`. I know that it is really seductive to use UIKit in a game for buttons etc.  but you've got many possibilities right in SpriteKit which replaces UIKit-elements.

For example you can use an `SKLabelNode` instead of an `UILabel`. Also you've got many more possibilities in SpriteKit to make your menu 'smooth' (For example with `SKTransition` or `SKAction`).

Also an example for a menubutton would be:

```
//Button
var playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImage.png")
playButton.position = CGPointMake(300, 300)

playButton.name = "playButton"

addChild(playButton)
```

Then in your `touchesBegan` method you can handle that button touch.

Also one very important point to only use SpriteKit is, that you can port a iOS game to OSX within a few hours.